# Calling C++ function from a C file gives an "undefined reference" compiler error

Tags: c++, c, c++11

I have the following files - main.c, RULE_MINE.h and RULE_MINE.cpp

**main.c**

```
#include "RULE_MINE.h"
int main()
{
  checker();
}
```

**RULE_MINE.h**

```
#ifndef HEADER_FILE
#define HEADER_FILE

#ifdef __cplusplus

extern "C"
{

#endif

//declare functions here
  void checker();

#ifdef __cplusplus

}

#endif

#endif
```

and **RULE_MINE.cpp**

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include "RULE_MINE.h"

using namespace std;

void checker()
{
  cout<<"whaaat?"<<endl;
}
```

I am compiling the following way

```
$ g++ RULE_MINE.h
$ g++ -c RULE_MINE.cpp
$ g++ main.c
```

For this, I get a compiler error

```
main.c:(.text+0x1947): undefined reference to 'checker'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit
```

I am unable to find what the error is. But suppose in the main.c file if I include **#include "RULE_MINE.cpp"** , then it is running properly and gives an output.
Can you please explain why I am getting this error?

Comment: Don't you mean RULE_MINE.h in cpp file?

Comment: Your compiling command is bizarre. `g++ -o <executable> -I/includes <sources>` is the idiomatic approach.

Comment: Where is file `RULE_MINING.h`?    (or is that a mistake for `RULE_MINE.h`?)

Comment: Why are you building main.c was g++? that is a c++ compiler, not a C compiler.

Comment: [You did not read the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12574420/560648).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace `void checker()` with `extern "C" void checker` in you `cpp` file to ensure correct linkage (`C` or cdecl linkage).

---

Your compilation commands are incorrect, you don't compile header files. Use:

```
$ g++ RULE_MINE.cpp main.c
```

And perhaps more flags (`-W -Wall -O2` for example)

or

```
$ g++ -c RULE_MINE.cpp
$ g++ -c main.c # or gcc -c main.c
$ g++ RULE_MINE.o main.o
```

Comment: In fact, you *can* [precompile header files](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Precompiled-Headers.html).

Answer (score 4):

Your implementation needs `extern` too :

```
extern "C" void checker()
{
  cout<<"whaaat?"<<endl;
}
```